# Moment method estimator of binomial population

Tags: parameter-estimation

If question asked... Let X~Bin(n,$\pi$). Find the methods of moments estimator MME of $\pi$. Book answer was $\pi$_hat=X_bar/n

Shouldn't it be X_bar/n_hat , or even better 1 -$\sum(X_i-Xbar)^2$/$\sum X_i$? by solving the 2 equations E(x)=$M_1 and Var(x)=M_2-(M_1)^{2} , M_i=\sum X_i^{2}$/n
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one parameter to estimate, $\pi$.

Note that  $n$ is known.

Hence from the first moment, $$\bar{X} = n\hat{\pi}$$

Hence $$\hat{\pi}= \frac{\bar{X}}{n}$$

Comment: ah so by asking just for 1 paramter estimation implies other is known basically? that is if others exist

Comment: not in general, but I interpret the question as $n$ is known.

Comment: I see your point, yeah this question confused me, in exam ill probably state , if n is known and second case if its not.